# Visual Basic Studio Project Icon Won't show up on desktop on the .exe, only in the window after it has been opened

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, icons

Like the title says. When I build my project, it has the icon in the list in the folder, but as soon as I drag it onto my desktop, the icon is the default windows one. Any idea? I am fairly new to Visual Basic Studio 2010, so please try to keep it simple. Thanks!

Comment: Have you set the application's Default Icon in the application's properties?

Comment: Hmm it just randomly started working... Hmm wonder what that was about. Thanks for the help anyways though. Before when I set the default icon it didn't work on desktop, only in folder.

Answer (score 0):

Place the application in a folder. Create a shortcut on Desktop and point it to your application. Then, the default icon will change.